# Generate PDF from ApiController using Rotativa and WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, rotativa

I want to create a pdf file using Rotativa framework from ApiController. 
In my project there is no any view. Content of pdf (HTML) is in the database.

Is it any way to generate pdf without View and ControllerContext ? Controller context is accessible only in Controller not in APIController...

I found this https://github.com/JustMaier/Rotativa/tree/ed7678eefdffb3995f5b6a3e9afb18903c648df8
but it needs View

Problem is in method BuildFile()...

**Start from here**

```
var a = new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf(pdfResult);
a.FileName = request.ResultFileName;
byte[] f = a.BuildFile();
```

**ControlerContext can be null here**

```
 public byte[] BuildFile(ControllerContext context = null)
    {
        if (this.WkhtmlPath == string.Empty)
            this.WkhtmlPath = context == null ? HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Rotativa") : context.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Rotativa");

        var fileContent = this.CallTheDriver(context);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SaveOnServerPath) == false)
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(this.SaveOnServerPath, fileContent);
        }

        return fileContent;
    }
```

**...but here can't**

```
    protected override byte[] CallTheDriver(ControllerContext context)
    {
        // use action name if the view name was not provided
        string viewName = ViewName;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        ViewEngineResult viewResult = GetView(context, viewName, MasterName);
        string html = context.GetHtmlFromView(viewResult, viewName, Model);
        byte[] fileContent = WkhtmltopdfDriver.ConvertHtml(this.WkhtmlPath, this.GetConvertOptions(), html);
        return fileContent;
    }
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you specifically want to use Rotativa ?

Comment: I need to use something that can convert html/razor to pdf and is free

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#create_a_pdf_dom

Comment: asp.net webapi ?

Comment: If your website can serve it, Chrome can view it (and thus generate a PDF of it).

Comment: This Project is a internal company project, it should be a service for pdf generation

Comment: Perfect, my link will help you do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
from  API  controller called MVC controller  it worked for me

API Controller

```
public class DocumentsController : ApiController
{
        public HttpResponseMessage Pdf()
        {
            PDFController controller = new PDFController();
            RouteData route = new RouteData();
            route.Values.Add("action", "getPdf"); // ActionName
            route.Values.Add("controller", "PDF"); // Controller Name
            System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext newContext = new 
            System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current), route, controller);
            controller.ControllerContext = newContext;
            var actionPDF = controller.getPdf(); 
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(actionPDF);// new StreamContent(new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "SamplePDF.PDF";
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
            return response;
        }            
}
```

MVC Controller

```
    public class PDFController : Controller
    {
            public Byte[]  getPDF()
            {
            var actionPDF = new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("YOUR_VIEW_NAME") )
            {

                PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
                PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
               PageMargins = { Left = 1, Right = 1 }
            };
            byte[] applicationPDFData = actionPDF.BuildPdf(this.ControllerContext);
            return applicationPDFData;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rotativa does not seem to be suitable for your scenario. It would be easier to use an alternative library like [DinkToPdf](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf) instead, which doesn't need neither view nor controller context. You should be able to use the HTML from your database with it.

If you **really** need to use Rotativa, you could try the following:

- add a dummy view to which you pass the HTML from your database using a ViewModel
- create a dummy context, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55857928/7217806)