# Rotativa Value cannot be null. Parameter name: context

Tags: c#, asp.net, rotativa

I am trying to use Rotativa to Generate a PDF and return the bytes, however I am getting the error:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: context

Here is my code:

```
public string getReportsPDF(string community, string procedure)
{
    SiteSuperReportsController controller = new SiteSuperReportsController();

    string value = "";
    byte[] pdfBytes = new byte[] { };

    if (procedure == "GetProductionTasks")
    {
        var actionPDF = new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("RedBluePDF", new { community = community, procedure = procedure })
        {
            PageSize = Size.A4,
            PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
            PageMargins = { Left = 1, Right = 1 }
        };
        try
        {
            pdfBytes = actionPDF.BuildFile(controller.ControllerContext);
            value = "Works";
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            value = e.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

The value returned is Value cannot be null. Parameter name: context

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing `controller.ControllerContext` is null and that `BuildFile` can't accept a null value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to move the call to `BuildFile` into an action method of a controller, where the controller context is available as property called `ControllerContext`.

If you need to create your controller manually like in your example, you will have to create the context yourself.
Derek Comartin shows in his blog post [Using Razor in a Console Application (outside of ASP.NET Core MVC)](https://codeopinion.com/using-razor-in-a-console-application/) how to do this for an ASP.Core 2 project. For your scenario, try changing the

```
pdfBytes = actionPDF.BuildFile(controller.ControllerContext);
```

to

```
pdfBytes = actionPDF.BuildFile(CreateDummyControllerContext("SiteSuperReports"));
```

using the following methods:

```
    private ControllerContext CreateDummyControllerContext(string controllerName)
    {
        var context = new ControllerContext
        {
            HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
            {
                RequestServices = GetServiceProvider()
            },
            RouteData = new RouteData
            {
                Values = {{"controller", controllerName}}
            },
            ActionDescriptor = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptor
            {
                RouteValues = new Dictionary<string, string>(),
            }
        };

        return context;
    }

    // see https://codeopinion.com/using-razor-in-a-console-application/
    private ServiceProvider GetServiceProvider()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddSingleton(PlatformServices.Default.Application);
        var environment = new HostingEnvironment
        {
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name
        };
        services.AddSingleton<IHostingEnvironment>(environment);
        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.FileProviders.Clear();
            options.FileProviders.Add(new PhysicalFileProvider(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));
        });
        services.AddSingleton<ObjectPoolProvider, DefaultObjectPoolProvider>();
        services.AddSingleton<DiagnosticSource>(new DiagnosticListener("Microsoft.AspNetCore"));

        services.AddLogging();
        services.AddMvc();

        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
```

You might need to add the Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions package.